# Best practice for shared r/w storage between nodes in Google Container Engine

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have an Ruby On Rails CMS app. Images are stored in a folder based on DB auto-increment ID. What will be best practice for sharing this folder between containers that run on multiple nodes?

The app are also caching cropped versions of this image files. If I use Google sql, I think it will ensure that there never will be same filename on the orginale written file. The cached versions should maybe be stored differently?